# OpenCV 3.0 building library with contrib modules and Java wrappers

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to build openCV 3.0 library with contrib modules for my Java project. I am using CMake 3.4 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. In CMake I  successfully generate data. Then I am opening ALL_BUILD project in Visual Studio and building it without errors.  After build I've got openCV-300.jar and many other files with extensions *.exe, *.dll, *.iik, *.pdb. What I need is file opencv_java300.dll and it is also there however it's greatly smaller than original opencv_java300.dll from standard library. Also when I try to run my simple app I get:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ..\lib\x64\opencv_java300.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Of course If I am using files from standard openCV version it is working like it  supposed to. So my question is what am I doing wrong?I have got contrib library from here https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib and I am building library following guide from here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md (How to build OpenCV with extra modules - cmake-gui part).

EDIT: I had to add directory to all generated files into `PATH` variable and it worked. But I am still searching for a different solution.

Comment: you should use `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` for the java wrappers, so opencv libs get linked statically (1 huge java dll)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would try this.

Comment: It worked, thanks again

Comment: @berak: Do you mind creating an answer that can be accepted?